# TinyMCE deleting all HTML content on paste

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm trying to remove all HTML tags inside a pasted content in TinyMCE 5.0.3.

I tested different solution but none works. The result always contains the encoded html tag (`&lt;p&gt;`) instead of removing it.

Did I miss something ?

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        tinymce.init({
          selector: '#DESC',  
          plugins: 'paste preview',
            format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
            toolbar_items_size: 'small',
            toolbar1: 'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link unlink | bullist numlist | preview',
            paste_as_text: true,
            paste_word_valid_elements: 'b,strong,i,em,h1,h2',
            paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
            paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: true,
            paste_webkit_styles: 'none',
            valid_elements: 'strong/b,br,i,em',
            forced_root_block : "",
            branding: false
        });
     });
```

The text copied in the editor:

```
    <p style="background-color: transparent; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; border: 0px none #6e6666;">
My text
</p>
```

The output result dump:

```
&lt;p style="background-color: transparent; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; border: 0px none #6e6666;"&gt;<br />Second text<br />&lt;/p&gt;
```

I put an example to http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2vhaab

Comment: Where specifically is this HTML content coming from? Can you reproduce this in a Tiny Fiddle? In this fiddle based on your config (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/uvhaab) I don't get any `&lt;p&gt;`. The only markup I get are `<br />` and `&nbsp;` where appropriate.

Comment: Thansk for your feedback, the post have been edited with an example of code that cause problems and a fiddle link (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2vhaab)

Comment: Using your fiddle and copying the example text, the resultant HTML content of the editor for me is: `My text<br /><br />Second text`. What OS and browser are you testing in? macOS Catalina 10.15.7, Chrome 86 here.

Comment: It's under W10 and I have tested with Edge 86.0.622.38, Opera 71.0.3770 or FireFox 81.0.2 , result is always the same: no delete. Could somebody else confirm this on W10 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the paste event like so:

```
                editor.on('paste', function(e) {
                    var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
                    var pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

                    // Replace line breaks with <br> tags to conserve breaklines
                    var modifiedText = pastedText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

                    // Insert the modified content into the editor
                    editor.insertContent(modifiedText);

                    // Prevent the default paste behavior
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```